# Creating G Suite subscription

Tags: google-reseller-api

While creating a subscription for customer using "G Suite Reseller API" POST https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers/customerId/subscriptions
can we specify :
plan.planName as "ANNUAL_MONTHLY_PAY", and renewalSettings.renewalType as  "AUTO_RENEW_YEARLY_PAY"

or the renewalType should be "AUTO_RENEW_MONTHLY_PAY" if planName is "ANNUAL_MONTHLY_PAY" ?
currently I do not have test reseller account hence not tested yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think so as GSuite Reseller API has this list of available [plans](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/concepts#plans):

- `ANNUAL_MONTHLY_PAY` — Annual commitment with monthly payments (more info)
- `ANNUAL_YEARLY_PAY` — Annual commitment with one yearly payment (more info)
- `FLEXIBLE` — Non-commitment plan with monthly payments (more info)
  `TRIAL` — Free trial plan
  `Trial` length is variable up to 30 days max
  Gmail daily sending limit set to 500 messages per user
- `FREE` — Free plan only for Cloud Identity Free Edition subscriptions

And for [renewalSettings.renewalType](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions) these are the accepted values:

- "`AUTO_RENEW_MONTHLY_PAY`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, automatically renew the subscription's plan with the same number of user licenses.
- "`AUTO_RENEW_YEARLY_PAY`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, automatically renew the subscription's plan with the same number of user licenses.
- "`CANCEL`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, the customer's account is suspended. For a 30-day free trial, if a payment plan is not set up for a trial subscription and at the end of the trial, the trial subscription is cancelled.
- "`RENEW_CURRENT_USERS_MONTHLY_PAY`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, renew the subscription's plan but use the total number of current active user licenses.
- "`RENEW_CURRENT_USERS_YEARLY_PAY`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, renew the subscription's plan but use the total number of current active user licenses.
- "`SWITCH_TO_PAY_AS_YOU_GO`": At the end of an annual commitment plan's interval, change the annual commitment plan to a flexible plan.

As long as the values/property was mentioned in the docs, it can be used.

Comment: the description for "AUTO_RENEW_MONTHLY_PAY" and "AUTO_RENEW_YEARLY_PAY" are the same, can you please explain the difference

Answer (score 0):

If the `plan.planName` is `ANNUAL_MONTHLY_PAY`, the `.renewalType` must be `AUTO_RENEW_MONTHLY_PAY` (As this is for Annual Plans with monthly payments)

If the `plan.planName` is `ANNUAL_YEARLY_PAY`, the `.renwalType` must be `AUTO_RENEW_YEARLY_PAY` (As this of for the Annual Plan with yearly payments)